# Sqlite insert optimization

Tags: performance, sqlite, optimization, insert

I'm trying to insert 3000 rows in sqlite using my mobile phone in android platform. I've tried all the possible suggestions but it is still not working. My original code is using individual insert statements and it is as follows:

```
private void insertData(List<MyDataRows> dr){
    int i = 0;
    private static SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    db=SqlHelper.openDatabase(dbFilePath);
    try{
        db.beginTransaction();
        for(MyDataRows dr:drs){
             db.execSQL(genInsertSqlStmt(dr));
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }finally{
        db.endTransaction();            
    }
}

private String genInsertSqlStmt(MyDataRows dr){
    /*I'll just keep it simple here. Basically its just formatting of sql statement*/
    return "insert into table "+dr.table+" values("+dr.columns+")";
}
```

This code will use about 22 to 26 seconds to complete. I find that its not fast enough so i tried with:

- PREPARED STATEMENT. Result is also the same. The total table that i need to insert is 80 tables for 3000 records. Is it because of the compilation of different tables that slows down the optimization process?
- BULK INSERT. By bulk insert i mean using a insert statement together with values that is concatenated by using UNION ALL keyword. The result is even slower by a second. About 23 to 27 seconds.

Is it possible that sqlite has already optimized the individual statements so that whatever optimization that i've tried is actually useless? I'm expecting some serious performance gains by doing so but i just dont see any improvements at all. Really need help in this. Thanks guys.

Regards,
Dexter

Comment: What is that `openDatabase` doing in the middle of the loop?!?

Comment: sorry about that. Its definitely not in the loop. I copied wrongly.

Comment: Is everything handled by a single call to `insertData`, or is it (or other similar functions) called multiple times?

Comment: Yes everything is handled by insertData. The MyDataRows object already contain the complete list that is required to insert into the database.